# Why is there no equivalent to `CompletableFuture.thenSupplyAsync()`

Tags: java, java-8

I am using Java 8, and have some completable future of the following form:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { ... }, executorA).thenRunAsync(() -> { ... }, executorB);
```

Now I would like to have the second asynchronous operation return some value, and I was expecting to have a function like `thenSupplyAsync` taking a `Supplier`, but alas it does not seem to exist. The following works, but is not very nice:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { ... }, executorA).thenApplyAsync(ignore -> { ... }, executorB);
```

I would like to write:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { ... }, executorA).thenSupplyAsync(() -> { ... }, executorB);
```

Is there a reason why `CompletableFuture.thenSupplyAsync()` does not exist?

Comment: I suppose, `thenApplyAsync(ignore -> { ... }` is considered fine enough. For example, look at `Map.compute()` javadoc: "For example, to either create or append a String msg to a value mapping:
 `map.compute(key, (k, v) -> (v == null) ? msg : v.concat(msg))`" Here `k` is ignored yet it is an officially proposed solution

Comment: […and of course the answer is always the same: because no one implemented it. Features start off as unimplemented and only become implemented when people spend effort implementing them: no effort, no feature](https://ericlippert.com/2012/03/09/why-not-automatically-infer-constraints/#:~:text=and%20of%20course%20the%20answer%20is%20always%20the%20same%3A%20because%20no%20one%20implemented%20it.%20Features%20start%20off%20as%20unimplemented%20and%20only%20become%20implemented%20when%20people%20spend%20effort%20implementing%20them%3A%20no%20effort%2C%20no%20feature)